# Postgres 11 update query on conflict

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Suppose I have an update query for a table with constraints (Postgres 11).

I do not know the constraints so I won't be able to determine whether an update query will fail or not.

If an update query failes due to a conflict I want to do nothing and return 0 (no rows were updated).

With an insert you can have 'INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' but this option does not exist in an update query.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Do you wish to abort the entire update, or just the rows causing conflicts? You can use a PL/pgSQL block to wrap your update, then catch and ignore the exception. To only ignore the rows with conflicts, you can move your `update...where` conditions into a `select` fetching IDs to be updated, iterate over them and try the update one by one, only catching and ignoring individual ones. Alternatively, you could do "reinserts": `delete..returning *` the target rows, `insert...on conflict do nothing returning *` updated versions, then reinsert unupdated versions of the ones that failed to insert.

Comment: Reinserts are pretty messy if you have triggers and if there are conflicts within the update batch that could result in a row being taken out of the table, failing to get back in both with and without updated values, because another row now locks it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CTE to get the result of the the `UPDATE` statement, and then return the updated rows using `RETURNING *`, but if it fails due to a conflict, it returns nothing.

```
WITH updated_rows AS (
  UPDATE your_table
  SET column1 = 'new_value'
  WHERE condition
  RETURNING *
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_updated FROM updated_rows;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work since the CTE gives the constraint error now.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but there is no reason to make a statement like: *I do not know ... so I won't be able to ...*. Instead that should prompt the question: *How do I ...*. In this case that would be *How do I determine the constraints on a table?* The the following is one such way:

```
select table_name, constraint_name, constrant_definition
  from (select distinct on(con.conrelid::regclass::text,con.conname,con.contype)
                con.conrelid::regclass::text  table_name
              , con.conname                   constraint_name
              , con.contype
              , pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) constrant_definition
           from pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
           join pg_catalog.pg_class      rel on rel.oid = con.conrelid
           join pg_catalog.pg_namespace  nsp on nsp.oid = con.connamespace
          where nsp.nspname = 'public'
            and rel.relname = 'non_standard_calendar'
       ) sq
 order by table_name
        , case when contype = 'p' then 1 
               when contype = 'u' then 2 
               when contype = 'f' then 3
               when contype = 'c' then 4 
               else 5
          end;
```

Then with that information you can pose a better question to your issue, or make the question mute.